# Change the color of sub-expression when the whole expression evaluates to a different expression

Tags: evaluation, color

I found it's tricky to colorize a sub-expression of an expression that changes to a different expression when it is evaluated.

For example, if I replace s with `Style[s,Red]` in
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}
$$, I get `HarmonicNumber[n,s]` with s colored red.

The solution I found is to evaluate `Style[s,Red]` in another line and use copy-paste to replace the s in the original expression.

Is there any better way?

Comment: I have no such problem if I change the `k`'s to red: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZtP.png or https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxJN3.png -- I suppose you did this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBxLA.png -- but it has the same problem as @BobHanlon's answer.

Comment: @Michael E2 Sorry, I confused s with k in my original post. I edited the question. What I did is this. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRzj9.png. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use an [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html)

```
expr = Inactive[Sum][k^-s, {k, 1, n}] /. k -> Style[k, Red]
```

[image]

However, this form cannot be directly activated

```
expr // Activate
```

[image]

Convert back prior to activating

```
expr /. Style[k, Red] -> k // Activate

(* HarmonicNumber[n, s] *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This produces an input cell that can be evaluated:

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[
  Defer@Sum[
    Style[k, StripOnInput -> True, FontColor -> Red]^-s, {Style[k, 
      StripOnInput -> True, FontColor -> Red], 1, n}],
  "Input"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[It basically constructs input equivalent to selecting each `k` in the sum and using the menu Format > TextColor > Red to change the color, which is what I did in the comment I left under the question.]